# EPoll C Implementation that I can call from Java through JNI

Tags: java, c, real-time, nio, epoll

Has any C guru ever implemented a Epoll Non-blocking selector in C that I can call from Java so I don't have to use Java's NIO Epoll implementation?

Comment: what's wrong with the one in NIO? If you describe your problem maybe this community can help you work around it better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am hoping that a native C implementation can be fine-tuned for better latency than the one implemented by Sun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find epoll sample program written in C by me. I hope that will help you  [Could you recommend some guides about Epoll on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247/could-you-recommend-some-guides-about-epoll-on-linux/6150841#6150841)

Comment: Thanks, but I would not be able to take this code and code something with Java + JNI. I guess I will make peace with the standard Java NIO implementations. :)

Answer (score 0):

SelectorProvider in Java 6 uses epoll if it's run on Linux with kernel 2.6 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

yes, java support `epoll` in JVM source code, you can find the follow code

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_sun_nio_ch_EPoll_epollCreate(JNIEnv *env, jclass c) {
/*  
 * epoll_create expects a size as a hint to the kernel about how to
 * dimension internal structures. We can't predict the size in advance.
 */
int epfd = epoll_create(256);
if (epfd < 0) {
   JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "epoll_create failed");
}   
return epfd;
}
```