# multiple threads and multiple tcp connections

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, pthreads

I have an application with multiple threads, one thread is creating 4 tcp connections, then this thread creates another thread that will handle the receive function for these 4 connections using poll or anything else, and the original thread (the first one) start sending messages to these 4 connections(round-robin). it's like below pseudo code,

```
main()
{

    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, sending_thread, (void*) args);

}

void *sending_thread( void *ptr )
{
    int i=0;
    int *connections;
    connections = create_connections();

    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, receiving_thread, (void*)&connections);
        while(1) {

        send(connections[i], "test"); 
        i++;
        if (i > 3)
        i=0;             

        }
}

void *receiving_thread( void *ptr )
{
    char *msg; 
        msg = receive(connections[i]);
        save_received_msg_to_disk(msg);

}
```

My question is How can I check my connections and bring up the disconnected one? for example, let's say connection1 went down, do I need to create another connection with the same fd, which is connection[1] in this case? or is there other ways to handle this case?

Environment is C/pthread in Linux

Comment: Do you *have to* do it like this with separate sending and receiving threads?

Comment: isn't faster to do it this way, what do you suggest?

Comment: Not necessarily. Try `epoll(7)` over non-blocking sockets from a single thread. Measure, compare.

Comment: I'm using that because receive is asynchronous, not sure how will use epoll to send and receive, do you have an example or a tutorial to share?

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247 , but of course it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Correct,what I'm trying to do is this, I need to send all the time and handle the received packets with multiple tcp connections, max number of connections is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some points based on your code and comments.

- While threads do allow some things happen in parallel, they usually have a non-zero cost in terms of more involved design that always boils down to synchronization. Like in your case there's no easy way of re-establishing one of the connections and sharing it between two threads again.
- I haven't ever seen an app where input and output streams are completely independent. I can imagine something like a tunneling proxy or a TCP-based VPN where that might make sense, but in general case some higher level protocol still imposes some request-response semantics that again would impose/require arbitration among sending and receiving threads.
- Things are different when you need *throughput* and when you try to minimize *latency*. Sleep-waiting on a mutex is usually OK for the former, but is rarely a good idea for the latter. Round-robin writing to several blocking sockets from a single thread hurts both.
- If you have heavy output stream(s) and sparse input, it only makes sense to use something like [`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html) to detect saturated connections and be notified when they are available again then starve others.

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but my <del>rant</del> list did not fit into the comments. Hope this helps a little.

#### Edit 0:

Here's the usual setup with [`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html):

- Make your sockets non-blocking ([`fcntl(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) with `O_NONBLOCK`).
- Set `epoll_data.fd` to your socket descriptor for each potential channel (four sockets in your example). Other options are possible with `union epoll_data` if you want to keep more complex structures then just socket descriptors.
- Use `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLET` to get *edge-triggered* behavior, i.e. be woken up when input buffer becomes not empty.
- Only set `EPOLLOUT` if you get `EWOULDBLOCK` from a `write(2)`, otherwise do output as usual. Same logic here with `EPOLLET` to detect output buffer space becoming available.
- Use `EPOLLRDHUP` to detect other side disconnecting cleanly (for abrupt disconnects you need to handle `EPIPE` error form `write(2)`).
- `epoll_wait(2)` gives you back number of events to iterate through. Do separate checks for input (`events & EPOLLIN`) and output (`events & EPOLLOUT`).
- On input read from `data.fd` (or otherwise associated socket) until you get `EWOULDBLOCK`.
- On output write until you get `EWOULDBLOCK` or you don't have more output data pending (remove `EPOLLOUT` in that case).

It looks like a lot, but is pretty simple once you get a hang of it.

You can also do non-blocking [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html), which is probably a good idea if you ever want to re-establish broken streams without hurting others that are still chugging along (`connect(2)` returns `-1` with [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) set to `EINPROGRESS` and you wait for the socket to become writable as above).

Comment: thanks a lot Nikolai, based on you comment which makes sense to me I'm gonna use epoll, my question here is I'm not sure how to use, never used it before actually, I've been reading about it since yesterday and the only thing I can think about is using EPOLLIN/EPOLLOUT, but not really sure how to monitor both events, is like this "if array[i].events & (EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT)) {do_somthing;}, how can I tell this is for input and the other is for ouput

Comment: Thanks a lot, I almost did that yesterday with the help of this http://epollwait.blogspot.com/2010/11/, I only commented this part   if (epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &ev) < 0)
                  {
                     printf("Couldn't modify client socket %d in epoll set: %m\n", fd);
                     goto cleanup;       and it worked perfectly.